# how can i get incrementing dates based on Dayname and Mindate

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select DATENAME(DW,'06/24/2015')
```

My table Looks like this.How can i achieve this one basing on day name from minimum date

```
Declare @t table (Dated VARCHAR(20),Dayname VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @t (Dated,Dayname)values ('06/17/2015','Wednesday'),
('06/17/2015','Friday'),
('06/17/2015','Monday'),
('06/17/2015','Wednesday')
select * from @t

Required Output : 
Dated   Dayname
06/17/2015  Wednesday
06/19/2015  Friday
06/22/2015  Monday
06/24/2015  Wednesday
```

Comment: What is the increment? In your example you need Wednesda, Friday, Monday etc. What is the logic to generate incrementing date? What is the maximum date?

Comment: Plz mention the "start date" and "end date" between  where the increment should happen?

Comment: then take last wednesday as maximum date '06/24/2015' @KiranHegde

Comment: @KavinChakaravarthi take 06/17/2015 as MIn Date and last wednesday means '06/24/2015' take as Maxdate

Comment: Date as varchar() is not considered a good practice at all.. consider changing it to date

Comment: you need only monday ,wendnesday and friday in week?

Answer (score 0):

Create the following function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.WeekDay(@DayOfWeek Varchar(9))
RETURNS INT
            AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @iDayofWeek INT
    SELECT @iDayofWeek = CASE @DayOfWeek
                    WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'Monday' THEN 2
                    WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 3
                    WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 4
                    WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 5
                    WHEN 'Friday' THEN 6
                    WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 7
        END
    RETURN (@iDayofWeek)
    END
GO
```

Now use it in your query to get the integer value for the day in question and use the `DATEADD` function to increment accordingly

Comment: can you put me the thing T-Sql query to achieve my output

Comment: to achieve the output you are looking for, I need relevant data in your table. The date values are all same, but the days are different.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code:(If you need only monday ,wendnesday and friday in week)

```
 Create proc Insert_date(
    @startdate date, 
    @enddate date 
    )

    as begin 
    set nocount on

    declare @date date
    declare @day varchar(15)
    declare @n int
    declare @count int

    create table #tab(Dated date,Dayname VARCHAR(10))


    Set @n=0
    select @count=DATEDIFF(dd,@startdate,@enddate)+1

    While(@n<=@count)
     Begin
     select @date=DATEADD(day,@n,@startdate)
     select @day=DATENAME(DW,@date)

     if DATENAME(DW,@date) in('Wednesday','Friday','Monday')
    begin
     INSERT INTO #tab (Dated,Dayname)
     select @date,@day
    end


     select @n=@n+1

    end

   set nocount off
    end
```

Execute:

```
Exec Insert_date '06/17/2015','06/24/2015'
```

Output:

```
Dated        Dayname
2015-06-17  Wednesday
2015-06-19  Friday
2015-06-22  Monday
2015-06-24  Wednesday
```